# .htaccess add a !not condition for group of rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

in order to accommodate some ajax I am working on a basic .htaccess rewrite.

the folder structure

```
main.html
alpha/
      alpha.php
      alpha.html
```

the main.html contains a div to call alpha/alpha.php 
the alpha/alpha.html contains a static include for the alpha.php as well.

I would like to have a clean url www.myUrl.com/alpha that calls alpha/alpha.html.

How do I add a !NOT condition for a set of rules so I don't have to include it on each, such as removing `[^(html|php)]` from each rule in a group, ie

```
set the following condition
^[^(html|php)]$
for

RewriteRule ^(.*)_aaa$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$1.html [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_bbb$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$1.html [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_ccc$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$1.html [L]

end condition and do not apply for 
RewriteRule ^(.*)_ddd$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$1.html [L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)_eee$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$1.html [L]`
```

current .htaccess

```
Options +ExecCGIn
Options -indexes

DirectoryIndex main.html

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# main start page
RewriteRule ^main$ main.html [L] 

# clean for alpha
# myUrl.com/alpha
RewriteRule ^(.*)[^(html|php)]$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$1.html [L]
```

thx Art

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using negative look-behind:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?<!html|php)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$1.html [L]
```

The funky little `(?<!html|php)$` means: the end of the string (`$`) that is **not** preceded by either a `html` or `php`.

---

EDIT:

Given:

```
set the following condition
^[^(html|php)]$
for

RewriteRule ^(.*)_aaa$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$1.html [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_bbb$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$1.html [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_ccc$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$1.html [L]

end condition and do not apply for 
RewriteRule ^(.*)_ddd$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$1.html [L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)_eee$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$1.html [L]`
```

You want:

```
# If this matches, (the opposite of !(html|php)), skip all of the following rules (3 of them)
RewriteRule \.(php|html)$ - [S=3]

RewriteRule ^(.*)_aaa$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$1.html [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_bbb$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$1.html [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_ccc$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$1.html [L]

# if first condition matched, we skipped to here
RewriteRule ^(.*)_ddd$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$1.html [L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)_eee$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$1.html [L]`
```

Comment: thx @Jon I will give it a try. But what I am actually trying to achieve is a preface for a group of rules so line 1 is (?<!html|php)$ then apply to rules 2-5 for example, rather than add it to each rule, possible?

Comment: @artvanderlay Not exactly sure what you mean, can you give a list of URLs and how you expect them to be processed?

Comment: I have updated my Q. to show a batch of rules I would like to have the condition applied to, then stop that condition for the next set of rules